# How do we solve such an equation

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I've been reading about the inverse function theorem and i tried to solve this problem that seems quite elementary:

Find where $f:\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2; f(x,y)=(2xy,x^2-y^2)$ is locally invertible.

The jacobian is given by $ \det(J_f(x,y)) = \left| \begin{array}{cc}
2y & 2x \\
2x-y^2 & x^2-2y \\
\end{array} \right| = 2y(x^2-2y)-2x(2x-y^2) = 2(x^2y-2x^2-2y^2+xy^2)$.

The function is invertible for every $(x,y)$ such that $\det(J_f(x,y))\neq 0$, but how can i solve for zero?. I know that $(0,0)$ will be a solution, but i'm not sure how can i get them all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Jacobian is incorrect. Note that $$\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x}(x^2 - y^2) = 2x$$ and $$\dfrac{\partial}{\partial y}(x^2 - y^2) = -2y.$$ Once you make these replacements, finding where the Jacobian is non-zero is much easier.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that your $f(x,y)$ are the real and imaginary parts of $f(z)=z^2$; it follows that you can only cover half-a disk about $(0,0)$, i.e., if you go around a disk by more than $\pi$, you will hit any point twice; $f(e^{\theta/2}) = f(e^{(\theta+\pi)/2})$, i.e., complex square roots on a fixed circle are $\pi$ units apart.